# Orientdb taking forever to load a graph (Large set)

Tags: performance, time, import, orientdb

I'm importing a file of important size , as a graph on orientdb 11M edges vs 20000 nodes .
and it is taking too much time in vain.
is there a way to optimize the graph load or to explore the max of  performance of the  machine  of 16G.

My question is why is it taking to much time ?
Second , how can I optimize that ?

Comment: How are you importing the graph? Are you using plocal, right? What kind of graph is it (distribution of edges)?

Comment: @Lvca , it is a huge graph, I'm importing the  vertices first and then the edges are created 3 json files ETL from each part . v1-hasedge----> v2 . I'm proceeding by the insertion of v1 ,then v2 and at last edges are created

Answer (score 0):

Some advice for a fast import:

- use `plocal` connection if you can
- use a transactional connection and commit in batches of ~500 records
- try to avoid reloading of vertices frequently. Most of the times, the biggest part of the time to insert a new edge is spent seeking the two vertices.
- if your graph is not huge and the use case is simple enough, you can try to have a look at this http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/Graph-Batch-Insert.html
- if your main concern is insertion speed, OrientDB ETL is not the best choice, use some custom Java code instead

Comment: I'm not allowed to use java . and I'm already using plocal and batch commit of 1000 .  I think it has something to do with the configuration of the server as i'm keeping it with the default parameters

Comment: plocal with java means embedded with the java program itself, so no network round-trip and substantially direct access to the storage layer. So you are working on a standalone server. "why is it taking to much time ? " can you give a metric? Too much time without numbers isn't enough. Moreover, a snippet of code used to load the graph, and a little bit of scenario: is the import one shot or should be repeated regularly?

Comment: Did you create an index on the vertice property(ies) you're using for the lookup when you create the edges between vertices?

Comment: @Lvca yes I did